# Command or Plugin to give a player an item with a colored/custom name and specific NBT?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Minecraft's /give command can give me an item with a non-colored name and nbt, but I would like to be able to get both at the same time. Is there a plugin or a way I can do this easily?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: The method to change font color is to use the section symbol, §  per the wiki, however, it's not clear if it can be used in commands: "In normal gameplay, the section sign can only be entered into book and quills. However, external programs can be used to insert it in other locations". I'll do some testing on this a bit later.

Comment: @Unionhawk, he said a non-colored name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minecraft sticking two commands in one command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/353511/minecraft-sticking-two-commands-in-one-command)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from a few specific cases, text in Minecraft is colored with § signs preceding it. The character directly following the § sign determines the color. The § sign cannot be typed in Minecraft, so you will not be able to enter it into the chat or into a command block in order to color the text of the name of an item you give yourself. However, third-party editors are not subject to this restriction. Many third-party world editors, such as NBTExplorer and MCEdit, will let you input the § sign into command blocks. Alternatively, in Minecraft Java edition 1.12 and up, you can create a function to give yourself the item, and you will be able to write the § sign directly in the function file.