# How do I combine the NBT tags from two separate commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have two commands I'd like to combine into one, but I'm not sure how to go about combining them. Is this possible?

Here are the commands. They work individually, I just can't seem to get them to work together:

```
/give @p jukebox 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:melon_block"]}
```

```
/give @p jukebox 1 0 {display:{Name:"Box"}}
```

Can you help me to add one of the commands to the other one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create tools that only break certain blocks, and also have a colored name?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/349279/how-do-i-create-tools-that-only-break-certain-blocks-and-also-have-a-colored-na)

Comment: I'm voting to leave open per [my comment on the linked question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/349279/how-do-i-create-tools-that-only-break-certain-blocks-and-also-have-a-colored-na#comment520549_349279).