# How do I /give a NAMED Item that also can only be Placed on a Specific Block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know how to /give a Named Item & How to Only have it Placed on a Specific Block.

but how/is there a way to Merge these 2 Commands?

```
{display:{Name:"[\"ITEMNAME\"]"}}
```

&

`{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:lime_wool"]}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine NBT tags in two different commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/353511/how-to-combine-nbt-tags-in-two-different-commands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can combine them like this:

```
/give @s <item>{display:{Name:"\"name\""},CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:lime_wool"]}
```