# minecraft nbt or somethin simillar need help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to make a villager that cannot be hit and has a custom name. How to I combine the tags `{Invulnerable:1}` and `{CustomName:"\"BlaBla\""}` into something that works? I'm using 1.14.4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine NBT tags in two different commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/353511/how-to-combine-nbt-tags-in-two-different-commands)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the java edition (version 1.13 and above) you can use `/data merge entity @e[type=villager,limit=1,sort=nearest] {Invulnerable:1,CustomName:"\"BlaBla\""}`